# Multi site installation with cPanel showing Warning: symlink() [function.symlink]: File exists in

Tags: multi-sites, installation

I want create multi site with drupal 7.I just started with below link http://drupal.org/node/960934 After setup show an warining

Warning: symlink() [function.symlink]: File exists in /home/ioss/mydomain/index.php on line 5

The PHP Code is symlik is given below

symlink( '/home/ioss/ashokks/', '/home/ioss/ashokks/test1/' );

in the above code snip drupal installed under the directory "ashokks" and test1 is the multi-site subdomain.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the issue, now. Previously, I created an invalid folder name for multi site under the site folder in drupal.

#### Wrong

- /home/ioss/ashokks/drupal/site/test1
- /home/ioss/ashokks/drupal/site/test2

#### Right

- /home/ioss/ashokks/drupal/site/test1.ashokks.com
- /home/ioss/ashokks/drupal/site/test2.ashokks.com

I hope it is useful for who wants to create a multi site.

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3817175/drupal-multisite-setup) helped me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Yes a complete domain name sub.example.com is required to be as the directory name.

Answer (score 0):

(1) You need to ensure if test1 does not exists there as directory to sub-domain. You will have to remove it and symbolic link will replace it and will point to main site directory.

Or alternatively....

(2) You can edit your sub-domain settings (from sub-domain manager in C Panel) and replace the file system path to `/home/ioss/ashokks/` so that subdomain can point directly on main site without involving symbolic link as `Options FollowSymLinks` can be disabled in some server configurations.

Comment: :When i pointing the sub domain path to "/home/ioss/ashokks/" [Main installation of Drupal] Also i have doubt.Where i place the symlink file?

Comment: I fixed the issue now...Please ref my answer.